# h2o GBM early stopping

Tags: r, h2o, gbm

I'm trying to overfit a GBM with h2o (I know it's weird, but I need this to make a point). So I increased the max_depth of my trees and the shrinkage, and disabled the stopping criterion :

```
overfit <- h2o.gbm(y=response
                  , training_frame = tapp.hex
                  , ntrees = 100 
                  , max_depth = 30 
                  , learn_rate = 0.1 
                  , distribution = "gaussian"
                  , stopping_rounds = 0
                  , distribution = "gaussian"
                  )
```

The overfitting works great, but I've noticed that the training error does not improve after the 64th tree. Do you know why ? If I understand the concept of boosting well enough, the training error should converge to 0 as the number of trees increase.

Information on my data :
Around 1 million observations
10 variables
Response variable is quantitative.

Have a good day !

Comment: How do you know how many trees have been fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to lower the min_split_improvement parameter? The default of 1e-5 is already microscopic but relevant when having a million lines.
I guess all trees after the 64th (in your example) will be trivial?

Answer (score 0):

If the 0.1 learning rate isn't working for you, I'd recommend decreasing the learning rate so something like 0.01 or 0.001. Although you state that the training error stops decreasing after tree 64, I'd still recommend trying to add more trees, at least 1000-5000, especially if you try out a slower learning rate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Yes I tried that but it's the same thing, just with more trees. The training error eventually stop decreasing and I don't know why.